Is there any way to block connections by process and hostname system-wide in Windows?
In macOS, a firewall app like Little Snitch can block outgoing connections by both process and hostname (as opposed to just IP address), allowing fine-grained control over which network connections are allowed.
Is there any way to accomplish the same thing system-wide on Windows? That is, being able to decide what outgoing network connections are allowed based on the process name (or service name if it's a service) and the hostname of what it's connecting to? I'm willing to consider third party apps as well as external solutions like special router configurations or proxy servers.
Some potential avenues of accomplishing this I've found which I'm hoping people can speak to:

A third party firewall app, though at this point I'm not sure if any of them are capable of doing this

Performing filtering through a router, though I'm not sure how that would work with per-process filtering

Using a transparent proxy / http proxy, though again I'm not sure how that would work with per-process filtering and I'm not sure if Windows services can just choose to bypass it

Special configurations for Windows firewall, though it seems like it can only filter by IP address

Something else I don't know about yet!



Windows Firewall supports per-application rules. What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this prior to asking? Can you please detail what you've learned and tried so far? Please note that simply asking that we recommend a product is off topic on this site.

@music2myear I'm not simply looking for product recommendations, and while a third party product might be able to do this, I'm interested in any method that can accomplish this, be it from configuring Windows, using external hardware, or any number of other means. I've edited my answer to list a few potential options that might work but that I haven't been able to get a clear answer about, in the hopes that someone can speak to them.

Any method that I am aware requires a third-party product. What comes to mind is a IDS.

@Ramhound Can you say more about what an IDS is, and how it would be used for this?

intrusion detection system

Windows Firewall, like music2myear already suggested. Start -> Control Panel -> Windows Firewall ... Left menu, select "Allow a program or feature through windows firewall" and you should be able to select the service you wish to filter in/out.

@Silbee As far as I know, that only lets you block or allow the whole program. What I'm looking to do is block connections from certain programs to certain hostnames.

@BriBri go take a look into Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced options and check the rules for windows media player. Those are examples of what you are asking for. While they dont have restraints for which hosts they are allowed to connect with, it is supported and can easely be added. I dont get the feeling you are actually looking into the capabilities for windows firewall but have already decided it wont do the job.

@Silbee I am familiar with Windows Firewall and its capabilities. When I configure a rule for it, I can specify what program, protocol, port, and IP addresses it'll apply to, but not what hostnames it'll apply to. I'm fairly certain it can only deal with IP addresses, not hostnames, though do correct me if I'm wrong.

@BriBri you're right about that. There are possible solutions to work around thatt, like a powershell script that rewrites rules after resolving hostnames.
